# Django models.ForeignKey Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following 2 apps in my Django project.  One app (player) has a ForeignKey that references the other app (team).

App 1 - players/models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

App 2 - teams/models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Problem #1** - Everything seems to work, but when I try to run `manage.py reset teams` I get the following error :

```
Error: Error: users couldn't be reset. Possible reasons:
* The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
* At least one of the database tables doesn't exist.
* The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlreset users'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: (1217, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails')
```

I made sure all my tables are InnoDB.  I've seen people suggest using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` as a fix, but I'm not sure how to best use this with `manage.py rest`

**Problem #2** - When I do a mysqldump, I cannot restore my MySQL db without running into errors.  My basic procedure is as follows:

1. Dump my db.

   > mysqldump --user=root --password=pass --result-file=MYBACKUP.SQL --compact MYDB
2. DROP the database, and CREATE a new one with the same name.
3. Restore my db.

   > mysql -u root -p MYDB < MYBACKUP.SQL

And that's it.  When I attempt to restore the first time, it gives me this error
    ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 12: Can't create table 'MYDB.auth_group_permissions' (errno: 150)

When I attempt to restore for the second (and subsequent) time, it makes it one line farther, but it gives me this error:
    ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 3: Table 'auth_group' already exists

I think those errors have to do with Foreign Key Constraints, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I know this was a mouthful but any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I'll post my findings here tomorrow, if any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: you should really have a look at South once you've fixed this

Comment: @mariusnn yep, I can `syncdb` fine and use the admin console to manage everything.

Comment: @ArgsKwargs I heard about South and it sounds like an awesome tool but I was hoping to use mysqldump just cause of the simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Problem 2** - So my problem with dumping and then restoring my db has to do with how I use mysql dump - the `--compact` flag is causing the problem.

This line ...

> mysqldump --user=root --password=pass --result-file=MYBACKUP.SQL **--compact** MYDB

... should be ...

> mysqldump --user=root --password=pass --result-file=MYBACKUP.SQL MYDB